# how can i synchronize different column's name in 2 differents database tables?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, microsoft-sync-framework

Hi i would like to sync 2 different database and tables and columns.i created SYNC app. by using a sync framework.it is hosted by azure. also i've read below articles:

http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/part-4-synchronizing-tables-with-different-table-names-and-column-names/
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/SyncFramework.html

 But i have a Nullreference exception. OrderTable havent got correct columns. Look pics. How to solve this problem.

```
namespace WorkerRole1
{
    public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {
        public override void Run()
        {
            // This is a sample worker implementation. Replace with your logic.
            Trace.TraceInformation("WorkerRole1 entry point called", "Information");
            Setup();
            while (true)
            {
                Sync();
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Trace.TraceInformation("Working", "Information");
            }
        }

    private void Setup()
    {

        string scopeName = "DifferentSchemaScope";
        string MemberSQLAzureConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MemberSQLAzureConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string HubSQLAzureConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HubSQLAzureConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection sqlMemberAzureConn = new SqlConnection(MemberSQLAzureConnectionString))
        {

            using (SqlConnection sqlHubAzureConn = new SqlConnection(HubSQLAzureConnectionString))
            {


                if (sqlHubAzureConn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open && sqlMemberAzureConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {


                    DbSyncScopeDescription myScope = new DbSyncScopeDescription(scopeName);

                    DbSyncTableDescription serverTableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("myTest.SourceOrderTable", sqlHubAzureConn);
                    serverTableDesc.GlobalName = "OrderTable";

                    DbSyncTableDescription clientTableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("myTest.DestinationOrderTable", sqlMemberAzureConn);


                    clientTableDesc.GlobalName = "OrderTable";

                    myScope.Tables.Add(serverTableDesc);
                    myScope.Tables.Add(clientTableDesc);




                    SqlSyncScopeProvisioning sqlServerProv = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(myScope);
                    SqlSyncScopeProvisioning sqlAzureProv = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(myScope);

                    sqlServerProv.PopulateFromScopeDescription(myScope);




                    myScope.Tables["OrderTable"].Columns.Remove(myScope.Tables["OrderTable"].Columns["OrderQty"]);
                    myScope.Tables["OrderTable"].Columns["OrderId"].IsPrimaryKey = true;
                    sqlAzureProv.PopulateFromScopeDescription(myScope);



                    if (!sqlServerProv.ScopeExists(scopeName, sqlHubAzureConn))
                    {

                        sqlServerProv.Apply(sqlHubAzureConn);

                    }

                    // sqlAzureProv.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);

                    if (!sqlAzureProv.ScopeExists(scopeName, sqlMemberAzureConn))
                    {

                        sqlAzureProv.Apply(sqlMemberAzureConn);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void Sync()
    {

        string scopeName = "DifferentSchemaScope";
        string MemberSQLAzureConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MemberSQLAzureConnectionString"].ConnectionString; //CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("MemberSQLAzureConnectionString");
        string HubSQLAzureConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HubSQLAzureConnectionString"].ConnectionString;  //CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("HubSQLAzureConnectionString");
        using (SqlConnection sqlMemberAzureConn = new SqlConnection(MemberSQLAzureConnectionString))
        {

            using (SqlConnection sqlHubAzureConn = new SqlConnection(HubSQLAzureConnectionString))
            {

                var localProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, sqlHubAzureConn);
                var remoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, sqlMemberAzureConn);

                remoteProvider.ChangesSelected += remoteProvider_ChangesSelected;

                SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator
                {
                    LocalProvider = localProvider,
                    RemoteProvider = remoteProvider,
                    Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload
                };

                syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
            }
        }
    }



    void remoteProvider_ChangesSelected(object sender, DbChangesSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Context.DataSet.Tables.Contains("OrderTable"))
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable = e.Context.DataSet.Tables["OrderTable"];

            //rename the columns to match the destination table’s column names
            dataTable.Columns["OrderId"].ColumnName = "OrderNo";
            dataTable.Columns["OrderDesc"].ColumnName = "OrderDetail";

        }
    }

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections 
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

        // For information on handling configuration changes
        // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.

        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

}

SQL:

id should be primary key....

CREATE SCHEMA myTest

CREATE TABLE [myTest].[SourceOrderTable](
    [OrderId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OrderDesc] nvarchar NULL)

```
CREATE TABLE [myTest].[DestinationOrderTable](
[OrderNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[OrderDetail] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[OrderQty] int NULL)
```

but it is not working. it produced an error on "void remoteProvider_ChangesSelected(object sender, DbChangesSelectedEventArgs e)"   That's Why remoteprovider columns name is not changed.remoteProvider Columns Names are "OrderNo,OrderDetail" but it must be "OrderId ,OrderDesc" look picture:

[image]

ERROR picture:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of *every NullReferenceException question ever*.

Comment: you misunderstand my question. i have enough information to solve this problem. RemoteProvider table does not include orderid,orderdesc.WHY? did you see my codes and articles?

Comment: I read your code.  You create a `dataTable` for no reason in particular because you assign it to something else on the very next line.

Comment: ok. how can i synchronize different column's name in 2 differents database tables?

Comment: can you post the local and remote table structures?

Comment: SQL:

id should be primary key....

CREATE SCHEMA myTest

CREATE TABLE [myTest].[SourceOrderTable]( [OrderId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [OrderDesc] nvarchar NULL)

CREATE TABLE [myTest].[DestinationOrderTable](
[OrderNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[OrderDetail] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[OrderQty] int NULL)

Comment: i added inside of my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your sync direction. 
it says Upload and Download, you bind the ChangesSelected on the remote provider which is your destination.

the event will fire on the download, your "destination" is now your source. so whats in you dataset is valid, thats the structure in the destination table where the changes were selected (which is now the source because the sync direction is reversed on download)

since you are doing bidirectional sync, you should have ChangesSelected event on both providers.

the local provider ChangesSelected should map OrderId -> OrderNo / OrderDesc->OrderDetail

the remote provider ChangesSelected should be the opposite OrderNo -> OrderId / OrderDetail->OrderDesc

Comment: i want to make only changes on remote. OrderNo -> OrderId / OrderDetail->OrderDesc it is not correct. can you give me a little sample. it is really important for me....

Comment: i suggest you pause for a while and think what is it that you want. the error you get above is correct. you are trying to find the local columns in your remote table. of course, its not there. do you simply want to upload? then set the sync direction to Upload and do the local provider changes as i suggested above. the whole logic above is to rename the columns after selecting the changes so it matches the destination.

Comment: i made it. but it is not working. i want to update only destination. but i need a mapping ...

Comment: what is not working? the codes above and the one you use is exactly how to do the mapping.

Comment: Sync is not working....

Comment: You can download here my code what is wrong?

https://app.box.com/s/ssm0x1ufsylwyj2vu23f

My Sql below:

id should be primary key….

CREATE SCHEMA myTest

CREATE TABLE [myTest].[SourceOrderTable](
[OrderId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[OrderDesc] [nvarchar](50) NULL)

CREATE TABLE [myTest].[DestinationOrderTable](
[OrderNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[OrderDetail] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[OrderQty] int NULL)