# How can i automatically compare and synchronize SQL Server data to another database?

Tags: c#, azure, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

i asked before a question '[how can i synchronize different column's name in 2 differents database tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006547/how-can-i-synchronize-different-columns-name-in-2-differents-database-tables)'

Everything is fine also i read alot of article:

Synchronizing Tables With Different Table Names and Column Names: http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/part-4-synchronizing-tables-with-different-table-names-and-column-names/

http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.nl/2013_02_01_archive.html

i know how can i use SYNC framework...

But i need calculate some fields and join two field :(Name+SurName=NameSurName) also i need calculation(BirtDate(Serverdb)------>  Age(clientDb))
How can i do that ?  i want to calculate below table.

Serverdb(first picture)  =====> clientdb(second picture)

Name+SurName=NameSurName

BirthDate=Age

## serverdb

[image]

## clientdb

[image]

Comment: It seems to be a job for SSIS which allow you transform before insert into the target table.

Comment: ok. why can not i solve this problem by using sync framework? can you help me? can you make a simple sample SSIS or sync sample?

Comment: My first idea is:
1) Make a fake table in server db with the same columns you want in client db.
2) Populate this table using triggers. For example: When you insert a register in your real table, a trigger calculates the age and concats name and surname and inserts in the fake table... 
3) You sync client db with this fake table...

Comment: agree with @Thiago - an ETL approach is much suited for this. you can force Sync Fx to do this by intercepting the ChangesSelected event to transform the data, but its not what's Sync Fx is meant for.